# Can we modify the authorization section of web.config file on runtime?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Can we modify the authorization section of web.config file on run-time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.authorizationsection.aspx

"The AuthorizationSection class provides a way to programmatically access and modify the authorization section of a configuration file."

I suppose it depends on what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know config files are made to not be modified on runtime, but to have a start up configuration for your executable. That's his function.

By the way:
[Editing app.config in execution time using the same App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679967/editing-app-config-in-execution-time-using-the-same-app)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the web.config file at run time... 
But by changing the configuration sever will reset the session 
so you currently logged in users will face the problem with logins

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's what I did and it works 100%:

```
var config = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));
var targetNode = config.Root.Element("location").Element("system.web").Element("authorization").Element("allow").Attribute("roles");

targetNode.Value = String.Join(",", Roles.GetAllRoles());
config.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));
```

and here is the web.config2:

```
 <location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin,Role1, etc..." />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```